# CSS `:first-child` on specific element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I took this example from w3-schools (see the [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_firstchild)). If I define my `p:first-child` to have a yellow background like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        p:first-child {
            background-color:yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p>This paragraph is the first child of its parent (body).</p>

    <h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>
    <p>This paragraph is not the first child of its parent.</p>

    <div>
        <p>This paragraph is the first child of its parent (div).</p>
        <p>This paragraph is not the first child of its parent.</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Everything works fine and `<p>This paragraph is the first child of its parent (body).</p>` as well as `<p>This paragraph is the first child of its parent (div).</p>`get the yellow background.

But when I then add a headline right before the first `p` element, like this:

```
...
<body>

    <h1>test</h1>
    <p>This paragraph is the first child of its parent (body).</p>
...
```

.. the `<p>This paragraph is the first child of its parent (body).</p>` no longer gets the yellow background.

Why? I applied the CSS style to all of the first `p` elements. When I add a headline, the `p` element after this is, obviously, still the first `p` element. Why doesn't it work then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's still the first p element, but it's no longer the first child (as described by the sample text). When you add the heading up top, *that heading* becomes the first child.

If you want the first p element in each parent regardless of its overall position, use `p:first-of-type` instead.

Answer (score 5):

`p:first-child` means select the first child of its parent if and only if it's a `p` element.

You want `p:first-of-type` which means select the first child `p` element.

[**More on `first-child` from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child)

> The :first-child CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the
>   first child element of its parent.

[**vs `first-of-type`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-of-type)

> The :first-of-type CSS pseudo-class represents the first sibling of
>   its type in the list of children of its parent element.

Answer (score 2):

Try `p:first-of-type`, instead. Using `p:first-child`, I believe, selects any `p` elements that are **also** the *first child* of the parent element. When you add an `h1` element in front of the `p` elements, then that `h1` becomes the first child, so `p:first-child` is no longer valid.

Answer (score 2):

`p:first-child` actually refers to any element `<p>` that is the first child of its parent.

When you add the `<h1>`, you are making it so that `<p>` is no longer the first child.

You may want to use [p:first-of-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I use to solve that this way (just to be sure is compatible with old browsers):

```
p:first-child,
h1 + p {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

This way you are going to work on all of the first child paragraph and all the paragraph that comes after every h1 (if you want to be more specific you could in this case improve the selector to "body > h1 + p")

Comment: I think in this case you would only hit the paragraphs that come after an h1, but for every other element except h1 like h2, h3, div, article etc., I would have to define a new style like p:first-child, article + p... but if you have a base similar on every page, your idea of course simplifies! Thanks for sharing

Comment: Np, is not flawless but useful. I use the adjacent selector very much for blogging development. After every article's title (h2), set the first paragraph as a quick description.